# Can't disable "Press the Option key five times to turn Mouse Keys on and off"

Tags: keyboard, system-settings, mouse-keys

Apple lets users who occasionally want the use of Mouse Keys to enable/disable it by pressing Option (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) five times. I use Maya, so I'm constantly using the Option key to manipulate the camera, and this usage often triggers Mouse Keys. Unfortunately, this disables the rest of my keyboard (see [this Apple KB page](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1297)) and I can't use other helpful shortcuts. I can of course disable it again, but it's annoying when I have to do it again and again.

I went to the appropriate place in System Preferences to disable this (Universal Access > Mouse & Trackpad), but it's greyed out. I've done extensive searching and haven't found anyone with a similar problem.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Comment: I'm currently on a windows computer, and I don't remember the exact path, but could you post the contents of `com.apple.keyboard.plist` or `com.apple.universalaccess.plist` (or something similar; see note above)? I believe you will find the files in `~/Library/Preferences/`.

Comment: Rooted around those a bit, here's what I found: com.apple.universalaccess.plist only contained one thing that could possibly be of any use, `useMouseKeysShortcutKeys`, a Boolean type set to YES. I attempted to disable this, but neither the System Preferences window nor the option key act like this had an effect. Nothing else has any potential at all.

Comment: Also, I couldn't find the Keyboard plist. I assume it has some sort of alternate name...?

Comment: I didn't know if it was keyboard or universalaccess. What do you mean by "disable"? Did you set the value to NO, or did you delete the line altogether?

Comment: I set it to NO.

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: Heh, whoops. Yeah, that'd do it. Heh. I'll try that later (when I can) and inform you of the result—in the meantime, submit that as an answer.

Comment: @Matt It worked, thanks for reminding me of that simple step!

Comment: No problem. Even the best of us need help sometimes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid editing plist or avoid command line, you can still do it in the prefs menu.

Go to System Preferences > Accessibility Preferences > Mouse and Trackpad > Options > Press Option Key five times to toggle Mouse Keys" (1st option). **You have to uncheck "Ignore built-in trackpad when Mouse Keys is on", first.**

Comment: Ahh, it was right under my nose the whole time!

Comment: Thanks!!! Same here. That stuff is really annoying, and if you fall into that trap, you are in real trouble! I did not know that such a thing exists and did a re-install of the os until I found how to disable that...

Comment: ouch! well hopefully the reinstall cleaned up a bunch of other things for you:)

Answer (score 8):

Change the value of `useMouseKeysShortcutKeys` to `NO` in 'com.apple.universalaccess.plist'. I believe you will find the files in `~/Library/Preferences/`. When you're done, don't forget to reboot ;)

Also, you can do this via Terminal by typing `defaults write com.apple.universalaccess useMouseKeysShortcutKeys NO` and pressing enter. You may need admin rights to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There's indeed an option to disable that permanently

Step 0

Search for  "Mouse Keys" in spotlight

Step 1

[image: step1]

Step 2

[image: step2]

Answer (score 0):

To disable mouse keys I went to system preferences

Answer (score -1):

timothy go to accessibility in system preferences and then mouse and track pad then click options and it is the first option

Comment: Maybe you can write it as steps rather than one line.

Comment: "went to the appropriate place in System Preferences to disable this, … but it's greyed out." I no longer have the problem, so it's moot, but your answer doesn't address my question.