# Can not copy and paste within Chrome from time to time

Tags: mac, google-chrome, copy-paste

Chrome Mac is a bit dodgy, I can not use copy/paste function from time to time, both  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>   and right-click menu. I must reopen it to enable copy/paste again.

OS X version is 10.10.3, Chrome version is 41.0.2272.118

Firefox and Safari do not have such problem.

Comment: reopen or reload ?

Comment: I meant the whole application can not copy paste, all pages. Reload can not fix this. Must reopen it.

Comment: Dear @sanigo, first of all, pls, read this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
Then, pls, add versions of Mac OS and Chrome. Do you have any specific apps working with keyboard, i.e. Typinator etc. which may interfere with cmd+C? Does your problem appears on any specific pages? Some of them might block copy/paste functionality.

Comment: The OSx version is 10.10.3, Chrome version is 41.0.2272.118, I did not give the versions because chrome has this issue all of the versions I have used, Cmd+C is usable in all apps but chome when it happened.  It is not about any specific pages, it is  all pages and even i close all pages and reopen. The only solution is quit chrome totally and reopen.

Comment: I have install an extension named "Easy Copy Paste", when i can not copy/pase by right menu and Cmd+C/V, I can use the extension to copy/paste.

Comment: Just wondering it that extension is creating problems ?

Comment: I don't think so. I installed the extension after I have the problem. It is a temporary work around.

Comment: I am wondering whether a single page that disables copy/paste could affect the whole app and all pages?

Comment: Hi, Any news on this issue ? I experience the same problem and it is really annoying...

Comment: Same here on Windows. Probably a chrome bug.

Comment: It seems that the only work around is to install "Easy Copy Paste" extension or reopen chrome.

Comment: Now I feel better to know that I am not the only this issue facer.

Comment: This is a bloody annoying issue.

Comment: Similar: [Copy and paste stops working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/131873/22781)

Comment: copy and paste not work with chrome 62 and mac 10.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been a problem for a L-O-N-G time now.  Here is a issue from 2009: [Copy and paste issues on google crome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/aaQvy5PPAEA)

While I am not a fan of Safari and I really hate FF, I found Chrome fast but full of issues.  My fix?  Opera.

It's not great, but it seems to be the best that we've got at present.  I am using it exclusively across platforms - OS X, Linux and Windows 7 - and it is very stable.

It's based on the Chrome engine, but doesn't seem to have the issues Chrome has.  For example, I have yet to deal with the Cut/Paste issue on OS X 10.10 and Opera.

Comment: Well, actually there's another story's being told here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7679531

Comment: @poige -  You do realize this answer was from 2015 and Sierra wasn't released until 2016, right?  That's now a new and different issue

Comment: \@… I do realize that people who would start having issues now can find this topic and that's why it's better if they would realize it can be different sort of issue

Comment: That's like saying my car's tire is going flat when its cold, so I just got a new car.

Comment: Still getting this issue in 2020...Unpredictability is driving me mad. Copy/Paste is a crucial function in browser usage. Can't fail on that. Would be interested to try some other Chromium based browsers that do not have this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Only thing I found is to quit and restart Chrome.

Comment: ✅this solution worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with a copy and paste operating in Chrome, but it only happens from time to time, which makes it all the more frustrating... namely, its unpredictability.

I have found one solution that solves the problem quite consistently, it is called Firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure why all the down votes if another browser doesn't spoil copy paste. I get not everyone would switch browsers, but if you know it's specific to one application - you can focus on Chrome settings or an update to fix it.

Comment: Already switched to ff for my main work.  But sometimes I have to test things on Chrome--what a pain that pasting doesn't work!