# Cannot copy and paste in Chrome with macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mojave

I just upgraded to macOS Mojave and noticed something weird. When using Google Chrome, I cannot copy and paste with keyboard shortcuts. I thought maybe the keyboard was broken, but it works in other apps. I can copy and paste using the Edit menu or by right-clicking, so the contents are definitely getting copied.

Chrome is up to date. I assume if this was a widespread issue, they would've fixed it by now.

Any idea of how to fix this or what might be happening?

Comment: It seems to be an ongoing issue with Chrome:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/191624/119271  The easiest way to test is to quit and restart Chrome.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for pointing that out. Based on that post, this has been happening for years. Somehow this hasn't been the case for me until now despite using Chrome for all that time.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun while we are waiting for Google - Chrome to fix it.

Try following..

Add Apple Keyboard shortcuts for Chrome

[image]

If you do not know how to do that let me know.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work