# Cut & Paste not working reliably on macOS Sierra

Tags: copy-paste

I recently upgraded my machine to macOS Sierra. In the last couple of days I've noticed that cutting and pasting is increasingly flakey. I thought initially that copy wasn't working since I didn't seem to be able to copy new content to the clipboard, but after trying various things I now have my machine in a state where Cmd-V or pasting via the Edit menu produces a different result to pbpaste. Are there any circumstances under which this would be expected?

I'm not sure how to diagnose this. In another [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131873/copy-and-paste-stops-working) I saw a request for the output of `kextstat | grep -v com.apple`, which I've added below.

```
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>
  146    3 0xffffff7f846da000 0x60000    0x60000    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (5.0.10) 23DD0853-7210-3AF2-85FA-1C7FF8F7D1BF <7 5 4 3 1>
  147    0 0xffffff7f8473a000 0x14000    0x14000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (6.0.1) 8FF2C637-0A5E-367E-B007-5B08655B1E8A <7 5 4 3 1>
  153    0 0xffffff7f8474e000 0x8000     0x8000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (5.0.10) C5D33477-F93D-36AD-8748-1EB1105FB93A <152 146 41 7 5 4 3 1>
  154    0 0xffffff7f84756000 0x5000     0x5000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (5.0.10) E5ABC825-5396-34A7-9B63-3A38E9142EEC <146 7 5 4 3 1>
  155    0 0xffffff7f8475b000 0x6000     0x6000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (5.0.10) BEFC91DC-800F-3F16-8388-50584243FB30 <146 5 4 1>
```

I'll probably have to restart my machine now since I really need to get work done, but any suggestions for when this happens again would be gratefully received.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to the ‘similar question’ you found?

Comment: Sierra (and iOS 10) introduced the [universal clipboard](http://www.imore.com/how-use-universal-clipboard-macos-sierra), which I'm guessing also introduced a few bugs. Are you signed into iCloud, with iOS devices nearby? Does signing out of iCloud help?

Comment: @grgarside Good idea, done, thanks. The issue related but not that similar, but several commenters asked for this information to help diagnose it.

Comment: @calum_b Thanks for the suggestion, I'll definitely try that next time this occurs.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7679531