# Clipboard paste hangs application for 30s

Tags: finder, catalina, performance, copy-paste

I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 (Darwin 19.3.0). My Mac frequently gets into a state where every attempt to paste from the system clipboard freezes the application I'm pasting in to for about 30s, meaning I see a "beachball" when hovering over that application, but can still use other applications.

It also happens with `pbcopy`/`pbpaste`:

```
echo foo | pbcopy
time pbpaste

real 0m30.031s
user 0m0.226s
sys  0m0.202s
```

It takes almost exactly 30s every time. Note that there is also no output from `pbpaste`.

I can temporarily resolve it by running `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist && killall Finder`, but the issue returns within minutes. Rebooting does not help.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try booting into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Also check if the problem occurs in a new user account.

Comment: It does not occur in a new user account (yet)

Comment: The issue appeared on the new user account after about a day of use

Comment: I have the same issue (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383624/pboard-making-mojave-slow-closing-down-apps) and nobody seem to know what to do

Comment: Are you using Handoff / Universal Clipboard with your iPhone? I have noticed a sometimes significant lag. https://superuser.com/questions/1124352/how-to-disable-universal-clipboard

Comment: @pkamb nope, I don't have an iPhone.

Comment: Anyone found any solution? This is very annoying. Core functionality is not working fine!!!

Answer (score 4):

- Open the Terminal application, found in `/Applications/Utilities/`
- Type the following command exactly:

  ```
  killall pboard
  ```
- Hit Return

This will terminate and relaunch the pboard process, which is the clipboard daemon for Mac OS. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried killing pboard and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Actually, killing pboard does stop paste from freezing, if only because it clears the clipboard. However, the freezes return as soon as I copy something again.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s try to understand what the system is doing during the hang:

1. Run the following command to enable kernel symbolication: `sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`
2. Reboot your machine and don’t open any apps except for *Terminal*.
3. In one *Terminal* window, run your `pbpaste` invocation.
4. In a second *Terminal* window, run the following, making sure you’re only running it during the window of time that `pbpaste` is hung: `sudo spindump -reveal -noProcessingWhileSampling`
5. After waiting for 10 seconds to collect a sample and another minute or two to symbolicate and format, you’ll get a file in `/tmp/spindump.txt` that contains a stackshot of every process.
6. Upload the file to [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) or some equivalent place and we can take a look to see what `pbpaste` is blocked on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately I ended up reimaging my entire system to fix it. So far it hasn't come back.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

Worked for me.

Ref. - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139334/445040

Comment: Hello, vijayinani. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.