# pboard making Mojave slow closing down apps

Tags: mojave, macos

I have a laptop with Mojave (10.14.6 (18G3020)) and I noticed it is becoming slow at closing down apps. The rest is fine. But closing down apps is noticeably slow -- it takes about 5 to 10 seconds to close an app -- irrespective of what apps and what the computer is otherwise doing (or how many apps are open). I noticed that when I close an app `pboard` consumes all of the CPU time. I have no idea what is going on, and why `pboard` is acting in this novel and annoying way.

`killall pboard`

does in fact solve the issue, but the problem of what's wrong with `pboard` and why it interferers with closing apps (but not at other times) is still unresolved.

EDIT: killing `pboard` solves the issue for a while, but then it crops up again.  The problem happens for different users.

Comment: "pboard provides pasteboard services.

     There are no configuration options to pboard.  Users should not run
     pboard manually." 
..  that's weird.. are you using a clipboard manager ? or handoff with another apple device?

Comment: nope, nothing whatsoever (no clip board manager, no handoff) -- I have no idea what is going on

Comment: As ever, first thing to do is to test the problem in a brand new user account. Create an account, log in, launch some apps, and then quit them. This will tell you whether the problem is at the user level or the system level. If at the system level, then it's likely to be some third-party software installation that isn't working well. If a user problem, it could also be third-party software, but that's being launched from a user account setting.