Copy/Paste randomly not working; works for a short time after killing `pboard`
For a few months now I've been dealing with this very frustrating issue where copy/paste would seemingly randomly stop working. I would then go and sudo killall pboard, then copy-pasting works for like 5 seconds, then it doesn't again (I think the process pboard restarts after some seconds).
However, as I'm writing this, it suddenly started working again! I had this exact same situation some time ago. I think if I killall pboards, then close my Mac, wait a few minutes, and then reopen it, copy-pasting seems to be working again. I can remember after I restarted it back then, copy-pasting again didn't work.
There are neither custom keymaps set to Command+C nor to Command+V.

Maybe this is a typo in your question, but the key commands for copy and paste are command-C and command-V. If that's not what you're using, something has modified your keymap, or something else is going on.

What if you use the copy/paste menu bar item? Do you see the menu bar "Edit" menu flash when you press cmd+v/c?

Have you seen this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131873/copy-and-paste-stops-working?rq=1

So it's happening again (after restarting my Mac). @LincD. yes that was a typo, and unfortunately none of the answers from the link worked for me. Also, I do see "Edit" both when copying and flashing

If the problem is reproducible, you should test in safe mode. If it doesn't happen in that mode, but reappears when you boot as usual, then you're dealing with a software conflict.
